# MFMailComposeViewController subject changes?

Tags: iphone

i am using apple's MFmailcomposer.in that when i type subject, the title of MFMailcomposer
is also changing, how can i avoid it?

Answer (score 2):

This is default behavior for the Class.  If you want to change it, you should write your own mail controller, or check out the one in [Three20](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20).  The class you want to start with is [TTMessageConposer](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/blob/master/src/Three20/TTMessageController.h).  You should be able to pick it apart to achieve what you desire.

Comment: i ran TTCatalog , but it gives the same output....when i type
subject ,he title of MFMailcomposer is also changing,
will you help in anyway?

Comment: you need to inspect the code in TTMessageComposer and figure out where they are handling the text field did change code